# How does increasing the duration of the transient response become a problem?

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, transient-suppression

I'm looking at the [TI TPS727 LDO regulator datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps727.pdf) and it says this:

> 8.2.1.2 Transient Response
>
> As with any regulator, increasing the size of the output capacitor reduces over- and undershoot magnitude but increases duration of the transient response.

So the datasheet is saying it's detrimental to widen a transient spike or pulse, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As with any regulator, increasing the size of the output capacitor reduces over- and undershoot magnitude but increases duration of the transient response.
>
> So the datasheet is saying it's detrimental to widen a transient spike or pulse, why is this?

No - the data sheet says that the **duration** is increased - not that the pulse is widened. The difference is subtle and important.
The widening happens, but it is a consequence of the duration.
BUT -  are they the same thing?
Well, yes and no.

Duration of transient response is the period during which the regulator is not in regulation.
With a very small capacitor the regulator may be able to restore regulation rapidly, relative to using a larger capacitor, but at the expense of large excursions.
The datasheet figs 17 & 18 show the difference between a 0.1 / 200 /.1 mA transient load and a 1 / 200 / 1 mA transient. It can be seen that the 0.1 mA post transient recovery is very much worse than for the 1 mA post transient recovery time - 400 uS versus 25 uS (note that they (naughtily) changed the time scale!.
This strongly suggests that the device does not have active "pull down" regulation - only positive drive variation. This is almost always the case with regulators, but leaves you 'at the mercy' of the energy content of the output capacitor - with time to fall back into regulation relating mainly to capacitor size and load current.

SO -  adding a larger output capacitor will usually reduce the voltage excursion caused by a spike BUT will mean the regulator is "out of regulation" much longer as a consequence.

How important transient magnitude is relative to out of regulation time depends on your application.

Answer (score 1):

It *can* be detrimental.  Or it may be better to have a shallower pulse, but not as good as it would be to have a shallow short pulse.

Answer (score 1):

> So the datasheet is saying it's detrimental to widen a transient spike
>   or pulse, why is this?

Because a transient will no longer be regulated, it will spread out and affect the regulated voltage. This can create a problem for loads that need a stable regulation. It also increases the time spent away from the set regulated voltage.